# How to stop the "continue" for NEXT iteration c#

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

While handling the negation in Sentiment Analysis, I came across this problem. I want the compiler to skip the "next" iteration, not the current. How can I achieve it in C#?
Actually I am applying a condition:

```
foreach(var line in txtbox.Lines)
{
     //see if line contains not, if yes, see if next line contains positive or negative words, if yes, negate the "rating".
}
```

The problem is when I'm negating the rating of"next line" as shown above, it is negated and again the loop comes on "that line" in next iteration, it's calculating the word as positive.

E.g:

line 1: NOT

line 2: GOOD

Not Good is considered -3 because of my condition[iteration on line1] and it counts it +3[iteration on line2] making final intensity +3 -3 = 0

1. How to skip the "next" iteration?
2. If not possible, how can I handle the problem? I've tried deleting the "next" line, but doesn't work, don't know why.
3. I just thought I can do it this way. I'll highly appreciate any other efficient techniques to handle it.

Comment: Replace `foreach` with `for` and increment the counter when necessary inside the loop body.

Comment: unclear. relevant part of logic omitted. please provide mcve

Answer (score 1):

Here's one simple way to skip an item in a `foreach` statement.

```
bool skip_next = false;
foreach(var line in txtbox.Lines)
{
   if(skip_next)
   { 
     skip_next = false;
     continue;
   }


   /* whatever "rating calculation" here */

   skip_next = /* condition to skip or not the next item */;
}
```

Not claiming this to be the best method (not even the cleanest code to do it), but without seeing your full code, it's a cheap way to do it

*PS: I haven't even tried to understand the whole "rating" problem since you are explaining things that don't belong to the question, and just answered a way to skip the next item in `foreach`. There's probably a better way to do it depending on your requirements.*

Comment: Thanks, It seems working. I'd used bool variables also but not in this way. It was really obvious.
And if you know any better way to handle the negation then add it in your answer.
Thanks once again.

Comment: @user2735708 it depends on your specific code... since you only showed a `foreach` loop, I used some simple code to do so in the foreach loop. If you show your full code, maybe a cleaner way might be found. If this solution worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer